# Returning NaN instead of -1

Tags: r

I'm trying to maximize a function and in my code in R I use the following function to make sure, that I get a value of A, which is between -1 and 1:

```
A=(exp(x)-1)/(exp(x)+1)
```

The problem is that, when I for instance evaluate the function at x=3000 or some other extreme value, it returns NaN instead of -1, which it should.

Is there a way to write up this to make sure, this does not happen?

Thanks.

Comment: why not to add and if condition something , `if (x > 710) return 1` ?

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just inserting an if statement.

Comment: Randy Lai's answer is much better than an if statement with a magic number in.

Comment: @Trengot no it is not magic. Just exp(710) is Infinite in R. (exp(709) no). And I agree that the simplification works better here but isn't rarely when we come with such simplification?( it is not a general solution).

Comment: BTW, an if statement is also not a general solution. No offense.

Comment: @RandyLai no offense of course. But i don't see your point. the if resolve the problem whatever you have an exp in your function definition. that's it.

Comment: it is not generally true, how about `exp(x)/exp(2*x)`? My point is that, one should try to do math hard enough to avoid numerical error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do a little math

[image]

so that, 
`A = 1 - 2/(exp(x)+1)` will do the job.

When `x` is large, `exp(x)` equals `Inf`, such that `2/(exp(x)+1)` is 0.

It is a very handy feature of R, but the implementation costs too much computational power. Sometimes, these are be blamed for slow speed of R.

Answer (score 4):

The `logit` and `probit` functions will return values between `0` and `1`.  You might consider using the [hyperbolic tangent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicTangent.html),

```
(1 - exp(-2*x)) / (1 + exp(-2*x))
```

which will return a value between `-1` and `1`.  In your case, you are dividing by `INF` when `x` goes above ~700, thus returning a `NAN`.